# Value of dynamic dropdown to push to firebase DB in polymer

Tags: drop-down-menu, polymer

I need to get the value of a dynamic dropdown.  All my other fields use .value and all work.  When I try to get the value of the dropdown, I get an error in the console log ... 'Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'.
My HTML looks like this....

```
div class="">
    <paper-input id="pxName" label="Patient Name"></paper-input>
    <paper-input id="pxAptTime" label="Appointment Time"></paper-input>
    <paper-input id="pxLocation" label="Location"></paper-input>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Doctors">
        <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[doctors]]" as="dr">
                <paper-item id="pxProvider">[[dr.name]]</paper-item>
            </template>

        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <div id="px-input">
        <paper-button raised id="addPatient" on-tap="addPatient">Add Patient</paper-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my function that is posting looks like this....

```
addPatient: function () {
            // console.log(this.$.pxProvider.value);
            this.$.patients.ref.push({
                name: this.$.pxName.value,
                aptTime: this.$.pxAptTime.value,
                location: this.$.pxLocation.value,
                provider: this.$.pxProvider.value
            })
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The reason is that the paper-item for provider is inside of the shadow-dom. You have to grab it using querySelector. ```For locating dynamically-created nodes in your element's local DOM, the $$ method provides a shorthand for Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector():

this.$$(selector)

$$ returns the first node in the local DOM that matches selector.```

Comment: Also, the approach above won't work, because you are going to have duplicate ID's for components; they are all using the same ID inside of a dom-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by moving the location of the 'id' from paper-item to the paper-dropdown-menu.  This captures the value and posts to database correctly  now.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="pxProvider" label="Doctors">
        <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[doctors]]" as="dr">
                <paper-item >[[dr.name]]</paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are within a new scope.
This means you can't use "this" inside your push.

```
addPatient: function () {
        var me = this;
        this.$.patients.ref.push({
            name: me.$.pxName.value,
            aptTime: me.$.pxAptTime.value,
            location: me.$.pxLocation.value,
            provider: me.$.pxProvider.value
        })
}
```

A other solution, which might be a bit cleaner:

```
addPatient: function () {
        this.$.patients.ref.push({
            name: this.$.pxName.value,
            aptTime: this.$.pxAptTime.value,
            location: this.$.pxLocation.value,
            provider: this.$.pxProvider.value
        }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: The only values that dont work are the ones that are dropdowns.  The name and aptTime work fine.  That makes me believe scope is not the issue.  I will try this code today and see if it works.  Thanks